# Why the Tween Class don't work inside a for with Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

#### Problem

---

I'm trying to make a `Tween` with many `Movieclips` using the for command, like this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < mcArray.length; i++) {

    new Tween(mcArray[i], "x", Regular.easeOut, 0, 100, 1.0, true);

}
```

But it doesn't works. I've tried change the code as follow down:

```
var tween:Tween = new Tween(mcArray[i], "x", Regular.easeOut, 0, 100, 1.0, true);
```

And it doesn't works too.

I can't use the `setInterval` or `Timer` because the `Movieclips` should be synchronized and the it may cause problems.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Make sure mcArray.length is not 0. If its not, use TweenLite. Boom, you dodge future problems such as this one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm trying make a library like the TweenLite and i can't use the Greensock cause i I do not have the license.

Comment: Why would you? TweenLite already made :) You think you could do a better job? What about mcArray.length?

Comment: Are you sure your use of Greensock wouldn't fall under their very permissive "No-charge" license agreement? http://www.greensock.com/terms_of_use.html

Comment: The mcArray.length have 10 Movieclips. I don't think would do a better job, just do a job made by me. (:

Comment: @Marcela, yes, i'm sure! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS3 Tween engine, very bad: by design, by performance etc.
If you can't use Greensock library for animation, you could use [GTween](http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/#features), It's great tweening engine under MIT Licence. Even without support and continuous improvement, engine is *much* better than Tween by Adobe.

Working example, after start, if will collect every object in the center of scene:

```
package {

    import com.gskinner.motion.GTween;
    import com.gskinner.motion.easing.Sine;

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class StackOverflow extends Sprite {

        public function StackOverflow() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        }

        private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            setup();
        }

        private function createDummyObjects(size:uint):Array {
            var result:Array = [], i:uint, object:Shape;
            for (i; i < size; ++i) {
                object = new Shape();
                object.graphics.beginFill(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
                object.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
                result[i] = object;
            }
            return result;
        }

        private function setup():void {
            var objects:Array = createDummyObjects(10);
            var i:uint, len:uint = objects.length, item:DisplayObject, middle:Point = new Point(stage.stageWidth >> 1, stage.stageHeight >> 1);

            for (i; i < len; ++i) {
                item = objects[i];
                item.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                item.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

                addChild(item);

                new GTween(item, 1 + Math.random() * 4, {x: middle.x, y: middle.y}, {ease: Sine.easeInOut});
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NicolasSiver, but is not this kind of answer I'm looking for. I do not want to use a framework, just want know why my code does not work. Furthermore, I believe that all these libraries have as "core" the Adobe Tween. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Libraries as core has Timer, not `Tween`. Tween is very buggy, so buggy, that even simple `for` could be a problem. And It's also answer on your question, problem in your code that you are using Tween ;)

Comment: So, the Greensock, FlashEff, GTween and others, use as "core" a Timer? But, is it correct mode? I'm surprised, looking for a wrong assumption... Rsrs!

Comment: Assuming that the movements are mere "Timers", I decided to abandon the idea of using the "Tween" adobe and create a movement from scratch using the functions of the package "fl.transitions.easing". Your tip was very good compared to this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your exact code and it works just fine. You need to load your array initially, and I'm not seeing your code for that.

Try this: make two test MovieClips and put 'em on stage with instance names 'boxA' and 'boxR'  Then run this code:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var A:Array = new Array();
A.push(boxB); A.push(boxR);

for(var i:int = 0; i < A.length; i++)
{

    new Tween(A[i], "x", Regular.easeOut, 0, 100, 1.0, true);

}
```

Works, no?

Answer (score 0):

If everything in your code is correct and the code is running perfectly fine, and the tweens just aren't working, then this may be caused by Flash's garbage collector killing your tweens before they can finish.

This issue is relatively well known I think. I have run into this issue myself. Here is an article explaining the cause and how to fix it. http://www.scottgmorgan.com/as3-garbage-collection-the-reason-your-tweens-are-ending-early/

Essentially what you have to do is make sure you have a reference to your tween somewhere in your code.

Here is some code you can try to actually see it happening:

```
var mcs:Array = [];
var tweens:Array = [];

for (var j:int = 0; j < 50; j++) {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip ();
        mc.graphics.beginFill (0xff0000);
        mc.graphics.drawRect (0, 0, 5, 5);
        mc.graphics.endFill ();
        mc.x = j * 6;
        mc.y = i * 6;
        mcs.push (mc);
        this.addChild (mc);

        new Tween (mc, "x", None.easeNone, mc.x, mc.x + 500, 2, true);
        //tweens.push (new Tween (mc, "x", None.easeNone, mc.x, mc.x + 500, 2, true));
    }
}
```

In theory every single red square in this code should tween to the right, but only about half do, for me at least. However if you comment out the second last line and uncomment the last line, it should now work because the array holds a reference to each tween.

Comment: I've tried do this but when i put two or more Tweens synchronized, the error still occurs. Exemple, when i create a Array of objects and put "tween_x" + "tween_y" + "tween_alpha" inside and play all. Anyaway thanks!